# Get Username from Amazon Access Key in Java

Tags: java, amazon-iam, access-keys

Is there a way to get the **User Name** attached to the **Access Key** for the credentials you're using to access AWS via Java?  I would like to be able to get the User Name that's defined in the **IAM Users** section so that I can setup user-specific buckets/folders and then dynamically point the script to them based on the access key's User Name (so I can change the access key in the future, if necessary, without changing the bucket/folder name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've now found a much better method of getting the user name from the AWS Access Credentials in Java.  The previously mentioned answer was a simple work around since no other solution was provided at the time.  This new method is actually part of the [AWS SDK for Java](http://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/) (it may not have been at the time of the original post).

Anyway, to get the user name, just use the following line:
`iamServ.getUser().getUser().getUserName();`

This returns a string that can be stored to a variable.  I'm not exactly sure why they set it up so you have to call `.getUser()` twice, but they did. Other methods you can use after the second `.getUser()` include: `.getUserID()`, `.getArn()`, `.getPath()`, and `.getCreateDate()`.

Note: I'm leaving the old answer as it does still work, but this is now the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Once again I'm answering my own question... I always seem to be better at answering it on my own once I ask others how to do it...

Anyway, you'll find the code below that will allow you to extract the user name for the access credentials you're currently using:

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.PropertiesCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.identitymanagement.AmazonIdentityManagementClient;

public class test {

    private static AmazonIdentityManagementClient iamServ;

    private static void init() throws Exception {
        AWSCredentials credentials = new PropertiesCredentials(test.class.getResourceAsStream("AwsCredentials.properties"));        
        iamServ = new AmazonIdentityManagementClient(credentials);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        init();
        String theUser = iamServ.getUser().toString().substring(27); 
        int userNameEnd = theUser.indexOf(",");
        String userName = theUser.substring(0, userNameEnd);
        System.out.println(userName);
    }
}
```

The execution is crude, but it works; or at least in the instances I've tried it has.  If you just use the `System.out.println(iamServ.getUser());`, the username will show up looking similar to this:

`{User: {Path: /, UserName: UserName, UserId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, Arn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:user/UserName, CreateDate: Day Mon DayNum hr:min:sec Tmz Year, }, }`

Otherwise the code shown returns **UserName** instead of all the extra "junk" in the string.  Anyway, I hope this helps anyone else out there that might be looking for a solution to getting the current access ID's user name.  If anyone knows another, better method, please let us know in the comments.